# If character found, then delete the current line and next x lines (Notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a problem deleting some lines from a character matrix file created by SupRip (OCR Sup Extractor). I want to make a regex which is going to do this:
- If character `l` or `I` found then delete current line and next 40 lines until those 2 characters are not found anymore in the file.

I want to know if this is possible with Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do this using regex.

```
Find: [^\n]*[lI][^\n]*\n(?:[^\n]*\n){1,40}
Replace:
         ^^^ empty string
```

Comment: You need to handle the case where there is less than 41 lines left in the file below `I`. I guess replacing  `{41}` with `{1,41}` in your code should do the trick.